# Bluetooth headset: why do I have to either re-pair every time

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I'm using a "Energy BT Sport" headset. Pairing is pretty easy.

Obviously I'm not always using the headset, I'm frequently switching between headset and speakers depending the circumstance I'm in.

The problem is that everytime I want to use the headset, I turn it on and my MBP automatically connects back to it, but audio doesn't output anywhere. The whole sound system seems to have problems because in that period the sound keys are not very responsive and if I'm watching a video (whether youtube or VLC) it freezes a bit.

So **everytime** I want to put back my BT headset I have to choose between:

**A.** Remove the device from BT settings and pair again. An incredible waste of time and very frustrating.

or

**B.** Tell MBP to **disconnect** and after an important lag it disconnects and then snap connects back and I have to click **disconnect** for the second time (it always works like this) and then after the lag it disconnects and then I can **manually click connect** and that's when it works.

Is anyone else having the same issue? Any fix?

Comment: Does it save the BT profile for the headset

Comment: What... ? I don't understand

Comment: In your sys preferences, Bluetooth, is the profile for the headset saved but showing not active? Second question: When you activate the headset what does it shows in the sys pref Sound- output ?

Comment: This is what it's shown now that I'm using them: http://i.imgur.com/uKEIKml.png And the output is the BT headset

Comment: next time press and hold the volume button on the headset.